# JQuery keyboard navigation. Why does this load /undefined?

Tags: jquery, keyboard

I've made this jQuery keyboard navigation to go back and forward a page in a gallery. It works fine except if you press a button that has the same url value as the page you are on. If that happens it loads undefined page.

So if you are on mysite.com/prev.html and the prev button has `<a href="prev.html" class="prev button">&lt; Prev</a>` you are taken to /undefined

Here is the jQuery i'm using.

```
/* Keyboard navigation */
if ($(".next").length>0) {  // Only execute if next button exists
   $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 37 : // Left arrow
        $('.prev').addClass("active");
        window.location=$('.prev').attr('href');
      break;
      case 39 : // Right arrow
        $('.next').addClass("active");
        window.location=$('.next').attr('href');
      break;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  case 37 : // Left arrow
    $('.prev').addClass("active");
    var whereto = $('.prev').attr('href');
    if (typeof(whereto) != 'undefined') window.location = whereto;
  break;
  case 39 : // Right arrow
    $('.next').addClass("active");
    var whereto = $('.next').attr('href');
    if (typeof(whereto) != 'undefined') window.location = whereto;
  break;
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm a JS newb and am not quite sure how to fix this... `missing ) after condition
[Break On This Error] if (type of(whereto) != 'undefined') window.location = whereto;`

Comment: fixed it. typeof needed to be one word and need curl braces around conditions.